# Python3 Shelve: how to append a value permanently?

Tags: python-3.x, append, shelve

I want users to append new values in shelve module. Everytime I close the file, appended values disappear.

```
import shelve


shelvePracticeFile = shelve.open('/shelvePractice', writeback=True)

shelvePracticeFile['funnyNames'] = ['lala', 'dada', 'mama', 'baba']
shelvePracticeFile['funnyNumbers'] = [3,9,18]
shelvePracticeFile['funnySkills'] = ['Python', 'Football', 'Gaming']

# Will try to append.

print('Lets try to append. Type in something')
myInput = input()

shelvePracticeFile['funnySkills'].append(myInput)

# Lets read and print the shelve file we've created!

print(shelvePracticeFile['funnyNames'])
print(shelvePracticeFile['funnyNumbers'])
print(shelvePracticeFile['funnySkills'])


shelvePracticeFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code actually works AND saves into Shelve. For beginners like me; If you keep running the code above over and over, `shelvePracticeFile['funnySkills'] = ['Python', 'Football', 'Gaming']` part will rewrite the dictionary and remove the value you have appended.

I hope this helps other people who are doing the same mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but it doesn't word at all, even in the first time.

```
import shelve
file_name="sh"

data=shelve.open(file_name)
for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')):
    data[chr(i)]=[]

word='angry!'
data[word[0]].append(word)
print(data[word[0]])
data.close()
data=shelve.open(file_name)
for i in data: print(i, data[i])
```

What is interesting, if I use data[word[0]]+=[word] without data[word[0]].append(word), everything works. Maybe something wrong with pointers?

Comment: When you retrieve a value from the shelve (`v = data['key']`), you are now working with a *COPY* of what was in the shelve and all operations after that (like `.append()`) are operating on the copy, not the shelve. `... += ...` works because you are assigning directly to the shelve and not the copy.